# parsing output with awk

Tags: awk, grep, busybox, ash

I am trying to construct a small shell script that takes the output from this command: nc 127.0.0.1 5556 2>/dev/null (output shown below) and parse it into individual variables so I can transmit via mqtt client. I think I need to use grep or perhaps awk.

So for example, If I want to parse the 5 values associated with wind0 into 5 individual variables how would I do that. I need to end up with $a=220, $b=0.0, $c=0.0, $d=8.2, and $e=0.

Thank you!

Baobab

Edit: turns out that the system I am trying this on is OpenWRT based so apparently uses ash or BusyBox and not bash.

```
20201103061623 th0 8.2 39 -4.9 0
20201103061629 wind0 220 0.0 0.0 8.2 0
20201103061611 rain0 0.0 153.8 0.0 0
20201103061547 thb0 22.3 32 4.8 901.7 1004.5 0 1
20201103061628 data10 0.00 0
20201103061628 data11 1.29 0
20201103061628 data12 0.00 0
20201103061628 data13 11.00 0
20201103061628 data15 108.00 0
20201103061628 data16 3.00 0
20201103061628 t9 50.5 0
```

Comment: `awk` would be the choice for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```sh
while read -r a b c d e; do
     echo "a=$a, b=$b, c=$c, d=$d, e=$e"
done < <(nc ... 2>&1 | awk -F '[[:blank:]]+wind0[[:blank:]]+' 'NF>1{print $2}')
```

```
a=220, b=0.0, c=0.0, d=8.2, e=0
```

Replace `nc ...` with your actual `nc` command line.

---

If you're not using `bash` then use:

```sh
nc ... 2>&1 | awk -F '[[:blank:]]+wind0[[:blank:]]+' 'NF>1{print $2}' |
while read -r a b c d e; do
     echo "a=$a, b=$b, c=$c, d=$d, e=$e"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion and I get a "syntax error: unexpected redirection". A bit of research and it looks like because I am using OpenWRT that it is not actually bash that it uses but ash or BusyBox. I'm not sure if ash and BusyBox are the same or different. I am totally lost when it comes to shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

So I came across a fix that seems to work. I have no idea why or how but here it is:

```
while read -r a b c d e; do
     echo "a=$a, b=$b, c=$c, d=$d, e=$e"
done <<EOF     
$(nc 127.0.0.1 5556 2>&1 | awk -F '[[:blank:]]+wind0[[:blank:]]+' 'NF>1{print $2}')
EOF
```

Comment: Running a command inside a here document is just weird. Anubhava's pipe solution is more idiomatic and less error-prone.